# WPF: How to use a variable from code as property value in XAML?

Tags: wpf

I am implementing a countdown timer. I have a `TextBlock` which is showing the time, using `DispatcherTimer`.

I would like to create an animation for that `TextBlock`'s `FontSize` property. I want its value to increase to 300pt at the point the timer shows 9pm. So, it starts with `FontSize` 8pt whenever the application is run and it keeps increasing and when the real time hits 9pm the `FontSize` should be 300pt.

Here's how I pictured it: Once the application is run, it will calculate the number of seconds it takes from that moment to get to 9pm; the result will be the stored by the variable `timeToGetTo9pm`. The problem I am facing is that when I create an animation in XAML, I don't know how to set `timeToGetTo9pm` to the animation `Duration` property.

Any ideas? Also, if my approach is stupid or confusing, please feel free to recommend a better one. Thanks.

Delegate body:

```
private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime currentTime;
    double timeToNewYearInMiliseconds;

    currentTime = DateTime.Now;

    //targetTime is a DateTime object set elsewhere, 
    //It represents the 9pm mentioned in the question body
    if (DateTime.Compare(targetTime, currentTime) > 0)
    {
        timeToNewYearInMiliseconds = targetTime.Subtract(currentTime).TotalMilliseconds;
        percent = 100 / timeToNewYearInMiliseconds;
        PercentageComplete = percent;
    }
}
```

Comment: chibacity has definitely provided a way out. And even though it does solve my case, I would still like to learn how to use a variable from code as property value in XAML.

Comment: @Borris I have updated my answer with example code of using a property from the code-behind in xaml.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not have a 'TimerFontSize' property in your ViewModel\Code-Behind and bind the TextBox's FontSize to it.

```
FontSize="{Binding TimerFontSize, Mode=OneWay}"
```

As your timer ticks, re-calculate the font size and set the 'TimerFontSize' property. If you have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged for 'TimerFontSize' the TextBox binding will automatically update and change the size of the font.

This pattern will use your timer, plus data-binding, to drive the animation.

**Update**

I see what you mean re. separating visual representation from data representation. My suggestion is the easy way. You could clean it up by making the exposed property an elapsed time or countdown value, and then use a [ValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) to get a FontSize. This would separate data and view concepts.

Here's a code example of exposing a property in your code-behind. Simply use the binding I previously detailed to hook it up. Ideally you would refactor the code into a ViewModel class rather than have it in the code-behind, just taking things one step-at-a-time.

```
public partial class TimerView : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private double _fontSize;
    private readonly DispatcherTimer _timer;

    public TimerView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1) };
        _timer.Tick += delegate {/*calculate font size and set TimerFontSize*/};
        _timer.Start();
    }

    public double TimerFontSize
    {
        get { return _fontSize; }
        private set
        {
            _fontSize = value;
            InvokePropertyChanged("TimerFontSize");
        }
    }

    private void InvokePropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }        
}
```

**Update 2**

And to separate model representation from view representation use a ValueConverter, e.g.:

Binding:

```
FontSize="{Binding PercentageComplete,
                   Mode=OneWay,
                   Converter={StaticResource percentToFontSizeConverter}}"
```

ValueConverter:

```
public class PercentToFontSizeValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private static double _DpiX;

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double percent = (double)value;
        double fontPointSize = (percent * 300);
        double fontDpiSize = (fontPointSize * (DpiX / 72d));
        return fontDpiSize;
    }

    private static double DpiX
    {
        get
        {
            if (_DpiX == 0)
            {
                Matrix m = PresentationSource.
                           FromVisual(Application.Current.MainWindow).
                           CompositionTarget.
                           TransformToDevice;

                _DpiX = (m.M11 * 96d);
            }

            return _DpiX;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Code-Behind:

```
public partial class TimerView : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private double _percent;
    private readonly DispatcherTimer _timer;

    public TimerView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1) };
        _timer.Tick += delegate{/*Calulate perecent and set PercentageComplete */};
        _timer.Start();
    }

    public double PercentageComplete
    {
        get { return _percent; }
        private set
        {
            _percent = value;
            InvokePropertyChanged("PercentageComplete");
        }
    }

    private void InvokePropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If nothing better turns up, I'll do as you suggested. My goal was to separate the logic of changing the time from the animations and styles in general. Either way, I still don't know how to use a variable from code as property value in XAML.

Comment: @Borris I have updated my answer with example code of using a property from the code-behind in xaml.

Comment: @Borris I had my Font Point-to-DPI size calculation the wrong way around - the code is now updated and correct.

Comment: @chibacity Thank you so much, now I understand what you are aiming for. Still, the font won't increase. I implemented everything you've written and additionally written the delegate body. I added that code in my question. Can you tell me what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: @Boris The calculation for the percentage value looks off as it appears to create an extremely small value. Add some logging statements to check this value as it is updated. Also add some logging to the ValueConverter to check that it is being triggered and what value it is returning. Some simple Console.WriteLines will do the job for logging.

Comment: @Boris Ah I see - Of course the value for the percent will be small at first as it is going to be close to zero. Adjust for this in the ValueConverter so there is a minimum font size.

Comment: @Boris  The percent calculation also looks out. I think you need to divide the elapsed milliseconds by the number of milliseconds to 9pm at the time you started. That way when you're half way there, you'll get 0.5 rather than some very small number i.e. 100 / timeToNewYearInMiliseconds.

Comment: @chibacity Thanks for all the help. I made it work in the end. Cheers!

Comment: @chibacity Hey, a quick one: Why is the animated `TextBlock` shaking up and down a bit while growing? Can it be avoided? Thanks.

Comment: @Boris Sorry not sure. I'd have to have your source code. Maybe it's something to do with LayoutRounding and using non-integral font sizes. Try rounding font sizes in the value converter and specify LayoutRounding in your Xaml on your main grid or what-have-you.

Comment: @chibacity I'll give it a go with the rounding idea. Cheers!